# How do you abstract page session properties?

Tags: asp.net, session, dependency-injection, webforms

I was following this [example](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webformsintegration.html)

example code:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    private Poster _posterDetails; 
    private Posting _postingDetails;
    private Property _propertyDetails;
    protected void Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null) return;
        _posterDetails = HttpContext.Current.Session["Poster"] as Poster;
        _postingDetails = HttpContext.Current.Session["Posting"] as Posting;
        _propertyDetails = HttpContext.Current.Session["Property"] as Property;
    }
}
```

these session variables are littered throughout the app and I need to abstract the retrieval of them. Say, later I get them from a db instead of the current session.

`Session` is baked into the `Page` or `Context`. How do I inject that dependency into the concrete implementation of a possible current property getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an abstraction around HttpContext:

```
public interface IHttpContextFactory
{
    HttpContextBase Create();
}

public class HttpContextFactory
    : IHttpContextFactory
{
    public HttpContextBase Create()
    {
        return new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    }
}
```

Then inject it into a specialized service for these settings.

```
public interface ISettings
{
    T GetValue<T>(string key);
    void SetValue<T>(string key, T value);
}

public class ContextSettings
    : ISettings
{
    private readonly IHttpContextFactory httpContextFactory;
    private HttpContextBase context;

    public RequestCache(
        IHttpContextFactory httpContextFactory
        )
    {
        if (httpContextFactory == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContextFactory");

        this.httpContextFactory = httpContextFactory;
    }

    protected HttpContextBase Context
    {
        get 
        {
            if (this.context == null)
            {
                this.context = this.httpContextFactory.Create();
            }
            return context;
        }
    }

    public virtual T GetValue<T>(string key)
    {
        if (this.Context.Session.Contains(key))
        {
            return (T)this.Context.Session[key];
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    public virtual void SetValue<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        this.Context.Session[key] = value;
    }
}
```

It will later be possible to replace the service with another storage mechanism by implementing `ISettings` and providing different constructor dependencies. Note that changing the constructor signature does not require a different interface.

That said, you should provide another service (or perhaps more than one) that takes `ISettings` as a dependency so you can make explicit properties. You should aim to provide focused sets of related properties for specific purposes. Your application also shouldn't have to know the type of property in order to retrieve its value - it should just call a property that hides those details.

```
public class SomeSettingsService: ISomeSettingsService
{
    private readonly ISettings settings;

    public SomeSettingsService(ISettings settings)
    {
        if (settings == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("settings");
        this.settings = settings;
    }

    public Poster Poster
    {
        get { return this.settings.GetValue<Poster>("Poster"); }
        set { this.settings.SetValue<Poster>("Poster", value); }
    }

    public Posting Posting
    {
        get { return this.settings.GetValue<Posting>("Posting"); }
        set { this.settings.SetValue<Posting>("Posting", value); }
    }

    public Property Property
    {
        get { return this.settings.GetValue<Property>("Property"); }
        set { this.settings.SetValue<Property>("Property", value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking...  What I often do is create a service:

public interface ISessionService
{
    object Get(string key);

```
void Save(string key, object value);
```

}

And then I implement this, which calls `HttpContext.Current.Session[key]` and returns the value.  It shouldn't be hard to create a `Get<T>(string key)` to return an object either.  Break all of your dependencies to use this (which is the hard part).

There is no seamless way to break the dependency... it has to be through a manual change.